# File can not read correctly

Tags: java, json, filereader

I trying to read a json file from dbpedia and parse it. But the code that i have wrote can not correctly read the whole json file and for that reason parsing error comes. Here is my code for reading and parsing...

```
URL url=new URL("http://dbpedia.org/data3/assembly.json");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String inputLine="asdf";
while (( in.readLine()) != null)
{
    if (inputLine=="asdf")
        inputLine=in.readLine();
    else
        inputLine+=in.readLine();
    //System.out.println(inputLine);
}
System.out.println(inputLine);
Object obj = parser.parse(inputLine);    

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Use `String.equals` to compare strings

Comment: error msg is like this
Error: Parse error on line 1:
.../ontology/assembly" : { "http://www.w3.o
-----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'

ectually i compare with actual json file and the output of "inputLine" variable and it is not completly same.

Comment: Side note: Consider to use try-with-resources to close your streams correctly.

Comment: Side note: Avoid String concatenation in a loop. Use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper method to read the file from url:

```
private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1) {
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read); 
            }
            return buffer.toString();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
    }
```

then you can call the method like this

```
try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readUrl("http://dbpedia.org/data3/assembly.json"));
    ...

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It's up to you, if you need StringBuffer or StringBuilder